# Nginx + Tomcat virtual hosts

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I need to configure Nginx as a reverse proxy for Tomcat. The problem is when I try to access the web application through a subdomain (myapp.domain.com), in this case is displayed Tomcat webapps root, not myapp.

**Nginx conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapp;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log off;

    server_name myapp.domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer by David solved the problem partially, because in that way myapp becomes the defaut one, and is loaded even if not directly requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in Tomcat's `server.xml`, inside the `<Host>` tag:

```
<Context path="" docBase="myapp" debug="0" reloadable="true" />
```

Then restart Tomcat.

Comment: It works, but loads "myapp" also when trying to access the root, for example with http://SERVER-IP:8181

Comment: However other apps load fine too, thank you David :) How should I do to avoid loading "always" myapp as default? It would be preferable loading it only when requested. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen when you load `http://SERVER-IP:8181` ? A blank page ? Redirect somewhere else ? Sorry I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: When loading http://SERVER-IP:8181 it should load the webapps root, therefore the default Tomcat page. When loading myapp.domain.com it should load http://SERVER-IP:8181/myapp

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do that, maybe someone else will know.